# Custom access callbacks for user entities not being called

Tags: 7, users, entities, hooks

I'm trying to implement some custom access control for user entities, in Drupal 7.

I've used `hook_entity_info_alter` to set

```
$entity_info['user']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_user_access_callback';
```

and when I call `entity_get_info` at a later point, I can see that this is still successfully set.

But `MYMODULE_user_access_callback` never ever seems to get called when I try to display users directly, or load Views of users.

It looks like the custom access callbacks are normally called from the `entity_access` function in **entity.module**. But the `user_access` function in **user.module** doesn't ever call them.

`user_load` in the user module calls `entity_load`, which calls `entity_get_controller($entity_type)->load(...)`

but this still doesn't seem to invoke `entity_access`.

So is setting `'access callback'` for the user entity a wrong way to go about trying to implement custom user access control? Do I need to override `UserController` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the execution order of the modules

> [How to change access callback of user entity when entity module is installed? (how to make sure my alteration is the last)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/93793/how-to-change-access-callback-of-user-entity-when-entity-module-is-installed-h/93826)